# Oracle 10.0 package shows INVALID status in reference on oracle 11g on import with IMPDP

Tags: oracle-11g-r2, impdp

I have imported dump of oracle 10 version with tables, procedures and packages to oracle 11g version.

While am not facing any issues with tables and procedures, certain body of packages compiles with **error**.

On checking the same packages in old oracle version, i ve noticed that the reference status of package body is **VALID**. But in 11g version, it is **INVALID**

Also there is a mismatch in dependencies of package from old version and new version.

Cud someone shed light on what am i missing?

I wana compile the procedure without any error in 11g version!

Comment: Are these your own packages? Are all the package specs valid? Do you have the same number of package specs?

Comment: @Colin'tHart  All are my own packages and yep they are valid, as am able to compile and run them in 10.x version. The issue is raised while trying to transfer packages from 10.x version to 11g, using impdp and expdp commands

Comment: You didn't answer all my questions: are all the specs valid in the 11g database? Do you have the same number of specs in the 11g database -- ie did all packages come across?

Comment: When you compile the package(s) in 11g, what error(s) do you get?

Comment: @Colin'tHart sorry..yep all the packages have came across..The discrepancies were only in References of the imported packages

Comment: @PhilSumner Error(3578,9): PL/SQL: Statement ignored
Error(3578,36): PLS-00302: component 'XXX' must be declared

Comment: Again: all the package specs in the 11g database are valid?

Comment: Presumably that XXX is a package, procedure or function name.  Have you checked the order of name resolution means it doesn't get resolved as you'd expect?  See http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e25494/general.htm#ADMIN11561 (11.2). I don't know if this has changed from 10g-11g...  because of this, I was caught out by someone creating a table called the same as the schema name recently.  e.g. Schema HR, table HR.

Answer (score 0):

Most of the times some object privileges are missing from the owner[s] of the imported objects.

the error PLS-00302: component 'XXX' must be declared

can be explained by missing synonyms and/or missing privileges on that object. Verify in the source database that the owner - or sometimes public - had privileges on the object 'XXX' and make sure this is granted in the target database too.

impdp does not give grants on objects that it did not import in the same session. (the not created by me syndrome) Most likely sys objects are playing a role here.